# Before Save Record Triggered Flow Along with Screen Flow Not Working Together as Expected

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, before-save-flow

**Context**

So I've put together 2 flows:

***Flow 1:*** Screen Flow - Takes input from a User and creates an Account record

***Flow 2:*** Record Triggered Flow - is Triggered upon Account record creation, has some other entry specifications and is a before save (fast field update) and essentially assigns values to certain fields.

I've essentially created Flow 2 to streamline some of the data entry requirements for Flow 1 so that the account creation process is a bit more streamlined if you will i.e. If the user fills in Field 1 in Flow 1, Flow 2 will kick in and based on Field 1's input, fill in other fields.

**Behavior**

So Flow 2 doesn't seem to be firing at all upon completion of Flow 1. However, when I create a new Account via the regular [New] button, Flow 2 fires perfectly.

**Question**

What am I missing here in my understanding of flows? Is it an order of operations thing?  Originally, I thought that perhaps we had some other automation that was messing with the values but that doesn't seem to be the case and then I observed Flow 2 working through the normal path of creating an Account record? Any insight here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified the entry conditions on Flow2? Have you tried the exact data entry in both via screen flow as well as UI? Unless Flow2 has some entry conditions which aren't being met, it should trigger just fine.

Comment: Do you have real need for Flow2 here or are you just trying out a use case? You could streamline the data entry requirements in the screen flow itself.

Comment: On the second comment above, I would say that if the processing in flow 2 is applicable regardless as to how the creation is initiated then that flow being as before save makes total sense. If it really is just for this initial screen flow case only, then you should move the processing into the screen flow.

Comment: If the conditions seem that they should be met given your inputs to screen flow 1, I would guess that the screen flow isn't actually using all the inputs as field values in the creation of the Account record.

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer if specific details were provided. I know you cannot just show the flow as text, but some screenshots would help.

Comment: @arut

Yes, I wasn't setting entry conditions correctly it turns out. Thank you for pointing that piece out. I had assumed it was getting set due to manual testing but it turns out we have other code setting it after save. 

As to why I'm implementing Flow2 - it's because even though we have implemented screen Flow 1 which is where we could do all this logic as well, our users for this particular group can also create records via an email plugin which we have less control over on how that page looks like --> plugin uses the page layout assigned to the user for that particular record.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW for the contribution as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just didn't configure Flow 1 to set a particular value. I had assumed it was being set since all manual testing had the value being set but I didn't realize that we had apex code updating the value after the record was saved to the database.